# Can I use javascript to add a bookmark that is not a http url?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have this bookmarklet, i.e. it does not start with 'http:' but with 'javascript:'. No issue with that, it works correctly.
The problem occurs when I want to deploy this to users. I'd like to present them a link they'll just click to add to their favorites. Whatever methods I use (examples found on the web, or JQuery with jFav), I end up with a javascript error 'permission denied' when clicking the link, though it works perfectly when the link to bookmark is a classic 'http' one.
I believe that's some security in browsers, but is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a security measure. If a user could be tricked into bookmarking and running a javascript: URL, that's pretty much global cross-site-scripting.

About all you can do is present the user with a javascript: link, and ask them to bookmark it via right-click-bookmark or drag-to-bookmarks. You should also write the link out so it can be copy-and-pasted and manually bookmarked, because some browsers won't present right-click-bookmark for a JavaScript link, and others may not have a bookmarks bar visible.

Comment: Yeah, I was expecting this answer. That's what I already use and I'm frightened by the number of users who don't know how to add a bookmark that way and come to me whining. Thx anyway.

Comment: Not to mention if you want to deploy updates to several bookmarklets at a time.  Delete old one, drag new one for every single one!

Answer (score 1):

You can ask your users to drag and drop the bookmarklet to the their bookmarks or toolbar.

Comment: I don't know what browser you use, but that doesn't work with IE8. That's for a corporate app and everyone's using IE6-8.

Comment: For IE the user needs to add the 'corporate site' to their Trusted Zone to enable drag and drop. Of course, I'll read your mind, that would be just to difficult for them.